# PHP script launching multiple times

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that launches another script in the background. Recently my host upgraded PHP and this pair relaunches the background script multiple times a second where it should only be launching once.

I reduced the two scripts to their most basic form and they still have the problem.

start.php:

```
<?php exec("/home/s*****/public_html/sandbox/process/pushupdate.php &"); ?>
```

and pushupdate.php:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php mail('*********@gmail.com', 'test output', 'testing'); ?>
```

The email never gets sent, but that may be a problem with my hosting company.

Comment: For the record, removing #!/usr/bin/php -q and running exec("/usr/bin/php /home/s*****/public_html/sandbox/process/pushupdate.php &"); has the same results. Running from a cron job however, works.

Comment: I have tried this test on several different servers, and the only common factor I can find is Cpanel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do your host allow cronjobs? If yes, use them instead of calling pushupdate.php from another PHP script. You'll solve two problems: if no-one is visting your site, your mail queue will still be processed. If your site is busy, there won't be unnescessary calls to pushupdate.php

A possible cause is a redirect, e.g. example.com to www.example.com.

start.php is called by the visitor, right?

Comment: start.php is NOT called by the visitor. It is called by an admin from behind a password protected directory. You can't see it here, but there was logic to not launch if it was already running.

Comment: @David Beck: you could also use cron jobs to call scripts in admin area, by calling the php command: "php /home/s*****/public_html/sandbox/process/pushupdate.php  >/dev/null 2>&1" Actually I thought you should call the php cammand also in your exec.

Comment: Running as a cron works. I would like to find out why running using exec doesn't work though.

Comment: If you look in your Apache access logs, does 'start.php' occurs more than once in a short term?

Comment: The logs do not show more than one request (as it should). I was able to run the script on my local computer without any problem.

Comment: How did you confirm that the script runs twice?